# Установка иконки в TabLayout внутри конструктора Fragment

Tags: java, android

Обычно, иконка в `TabLayout` ставится таким образом:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabone);
```

... но я хочу сделать это прямо в конструкторе фрагмента, который будем подгружать при выборе вкладки:

```
public static TabOne getInstance(Context context){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    TabOneFragment fragment = new TabOneFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    fragment.setContext(context);
    fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tabOneTitle)); // работает
    fragment.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabone); // нет эффекта, но приложение работает

    return fragment;
}
```

Чего я не понимаю: каким образом `TabLayout` определяет, что `fragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.tabOneTitle));` - это была команда установки заголовка на вкладку, и почему таким же образом (т. е. `fragment.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_inbox);`) не хочет ставить иконку?

Фрагмент унаследован от абстрактного класса:

```
public class AbstractFragment extends Fragment{

    private String title;
    private int iconID;
    protected Context context;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setIcon(int iconID){
        this.iconID = iconID;
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
private void initTabs(){
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

// Хочу по-другому
// tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabone);
}
```

Адаптер:

```
public class TabsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Map<Integer, AbstractTabFragment> tabs;
    private Context context;

    public TabsFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        initTabsMap(context);
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return tabs.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    public void getTabIcon(int position){
        //return tabs.get(position).getIcon();
        tabs.get(position).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_inbox);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return tabs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }

    private void initTabsMap(Context context){
        tabs = new HashMap<>();
        tabs.put(0, TabOneFragment.getInstance(context));
        tabs.put(1, TabTwoFragment.getInstance(context));
        tabs.put(2, TabThreeFragment.getInstance(context));
        tabs.put(3, TabFourFragment.getInstance(context));
    }
}
```

На всякий случай скажу, что заголовки мне не нужны и я сразу же уберу `fragment.setTitle()`, как только иконки отобразятся.

Comment: Покажите код установки иконки в tabLayout

Comment: В смысле в адаптере? Добавил. Полагаю, это не то, что Вы хотели увидеть, но я того и не понимаю, как правильно установить иконку внутри конструктора, потому никого другого кода установки нет.

Comment: Где у вас происходит вызов вот этого метода `tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabone);` ?

Comment: На момент написания вопроса - из-за нехватки понимания нигде не было. Потом попробовал так:  `public void getTabIcon(int position){
        tabs.get(position).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_inbox);
    }` в адаптере. Эффекта нет.

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста весь адаптер

Comment: Вас понял. Заменил код адаптера полным.

Comment: У вас нет нигде вызова метода `tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabone);` Вам нужно это прописать где есть доступ к tablayout. Сейчас вы передаете иконку во фрагмент  и ничего с ней не делаете. А нужно еще и  в tablayout установить

Comment: Реализацию `TabLayout ` создал в методе `initTabls()` класса `MainActivity`. Получается, что нельзя добавить иконки вне `intTabs`? А почему тогда заголовки добавляются? Я смотрю, `getPageTitle` нигде не вызывается, получается что `FragmentPagerAdapter` добавляет заголовки в табы автоматически.

Comment: Потому что viewpager связан с tablayout через метод setupviewpager. Иконки надо дополнительно пробрасывать

Comment: Понял. Жаль, что придётся MainActivity засорять подобными однообразными командами. Или есть какие-то альтернативы?

Comment: Можете сделать getActivity.findViewById("id tablayout") и делать установку иконок в фрагменте

Comment: Отлично, получилось! Спасибо большое за Ваши объяснения.